# $E[X_i]=\mu$ Statistics and Probability Mysteries

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I realize I have over-flooded this forum with questions regarding probability recently, but I do not have access to a teacher, and have to learn these things by myself. I have made some good progress compared to what I knew about probability some weeks ago BUT, I am still very unsure of myself, and ...

I have to say I found it difficult to find reliable sources on the topic, and text books or documents on the internet explaining things really clearly. For example, while learning (reading) about sampling distribution and CLT, I wanted to understand why $E[\bar X] = \mu$.

### I think I get it right here!

So I understand this from all the books I read on the topic. You have a population (lets say finite) and you have lots elements in it which you call $x_1, x_2, ... x_N$ where $N$ is the total number of elements in the population (since the population is finite). Good.

Now you can compute the **population mean** as: $\mu = {1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$

The **expected value** equation is:

$E[X] = \sum_{i=1} {p_i X_i}$

Imagine you have 10 cards labelled with numbers on them (0, 1, or 2), and that you have 3 0s, 5 1s, and 2 2s. Now you could compute the mean of this population by doing:

$\mu = {1 \over 10}(0+0+1+1+1+1+1+2+2+2) = 1.1$$

and you could use the expected value formulation, knowing that assuming you know your population distribution before hand, you can say that your **sample space** is S={0,1,2} (*is that correct, your sample space are the possible outcomes?*). So the probability distribution would be Pr(0) = 0.2, Pr(1) = 0.5 and Pr(2) = 0.3. Thus:

E[X] = 0.2 * 0 + 0.5 * 1 + 0.3 * 2 = 1.1$$

Great we get the same results.

Now we don't want (because the population is too large or even infinite) to compute the population mean so we use a sample mean instead. We draw elements from the population, for instance $n$ of them and compute their average:

$\bar X = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

I think I am confused here because we use $X_i$ on the right inside instead of $x$. I understand it this way: imagine you randomly draw a number between 1 and 10, imagine it is r = 3, and this number indicates the card you need to pick from the population of 10 cards (you shuffled the cards before and put them on the table from left to right). The number on this card is 2. So what $X_i$ is in the above equation for the sample mean is this number 2. Correct? This is our random variable which we could write $X_1 = 2$ (we put the card back on the table, draw with replacement, shuffle the cards again, etc.) and we repeat this experience $n$ times to get the following series of Xs: $X_1 = 2, X_2 = 0, X_3 = 1, ... X_n = 2$. And finally we compute our sample mean which is an average of all these Xs:

$\bar X = {1 \over n} (2 + 0 + 1 + ... 2)$

where the $1 \over n$ is there because again the way we drew the cards from the population was done in a "uniform" way (we didn't "give more importance" to cards on the left for instance when we drew them).

So back to our problem, proving that $E[\bar X] = \mu$.

### I think I get it wrong here!

Unfortunately I am lost here! So if I understand the equation for the expected mean correctly it's a sum of weighted random variables (where the weight is the probability associated with this random variable). So technically if we wanted to calculated the expected value of a sample mean (where the sample mean is already a mean of drawn elements from the population), we would need to calculate many samples means, weight them with their associated probability (which I understand in this case is close to a normal distribution) and add up the results. No ?

$E[\bar X] = \sum_{i=1}^{NN} w_i \bar X_i$

where $\bar X_1 = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $\bar X_2 = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, etc.

So I think I am thinking wrong at this point because in books they define this expected value differently, they say since:

$\bar X = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

thus

$E[\bar X] = E[{1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i]$

$E[\bar X] = {1 \over n}E[X_1] + {1 \over n}E[X_2] + ... {1 \over n}E[X_n]$

and then they say something incredible in the sense to me not justified at all, which is that **"since the expected value of a random value is the mean" (WHERE IS THAT PROVED?)**

EDIT: so I realise that I wrote above that $E[X]$ and the $\mu$ with my card example were the same, the problem I have with that, is that my example was only working with discrete r.v. and finite population. I believe to hold true, the $E[\bar X] = \mu$ equality should be proved for any population (finite or not) and a r.v that is either continuous or discrete. Does such a proof exist?

then we have:

$E[\bar X] = n \times {1 \over n} \mu = \mu$

So where I would really like to get some help, is really on the last part.

1) why do we compute the expected value of the mean as $E[\bar X] = E[{1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i]$ rather than with the equation for the expected value $\sum_{i=1} {p_i X_i}$?

2) where is this coming from? **"Since $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are each random variable, their expected value will be equal to the probability mean $\mu$."**?????

I know the post is very long, but I hope this will be useful to many more people in the future, trying to understand why we use x rather than X, etc., etc. But if the real mathematicians out there, could please help me doing the last miles on my journey to "starting to understand" statistics it would be FANTASTIC!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A "population" or a "sample" is a *collection of random variables*, for which we usually assume that *each* has the same characteristics, like mean and variance, or even that they are fully *identically distributed*. This is part of the initial assumptions. This means that *by assumption*

$E[X_1] = E[X_2] = ... = E[X_n] = \mu$

Also, yes your sample space in your example is $S=\{0,1,2\}$ i.e. the set of *elementary events*. Just don't confuse it with the sigma-algebras that can be defined based on this set, sigma algebras on which probabilities are actually defined, and permit to consider more complex situations than "draw one card". For example, with the same cards you may want to study the probabilities related to "draw two cards". In that case you have to consider the sigma-algebra that accomodates these "two-card" events, which are not "elementary" anymore.

Comment: So in your examples (and I am trying to understand this below) and means $X_1$ here exactly. Is it 1 element you drew from the population, or does it represents something else ? A sample to me, can be either 1 or more than one elements randomly picked from the population. So do you call this sample $X_1$ or do you call each element you randomly draw and making this sample $X_1, X_2, ...X_n$ where n is the sample size?

Comment: In some fields, the word "sample" is used to denote just one observation. In other fields, the word "sample" is used to denote a collection of observations (since the size of the sample can be unity, one could say that these uses do not conflict, but I am writing what is _usually_ meant by the word). I use it in the sense of a collection of observations, where each observation represents a realization of a distinct random variable. Further we use capital $X$ to refer to the random variable (which is a function) and lower-case $x$ to distinguish the "draw", the realized value of this r.v.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try to rephrase and please tell me if I get that right. So you have population, you draw "elements" from this population, these randomly selected or drawn elements can be labelled $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ because you drew $n$ of them, and lower case because each one represents an observation. One possible way of making a random variable, is to sum up for example these $x$s. Example $X_1 = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$. BUT, you can only draw 1 single element from the population and call each one of these draws a random var: $X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ... X_n = x_n$. Am I correct?

Comment: (continue) then what you statisticians or mathematicians refer to when you use the letter n in in the equations, it is the number of these r.v.s or Xs. If other words, to be perfectly clear we should NOT really use n when you make more than 1 observations to compute a r.v. I will use say $m$ instead: X_1=x_1+x_2+...x_m and we have $n$ r.v.: $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ each being a sum of $m$ observations? (sorry in prev. comment I meant to say "BUT, you can ALSO draw 1 single element ...")

Comment: Sorry I think I need to go back to the basics. I am reading Wiki. I think I just can't understand because in fact, X is not a fixed value, but should really be seen a function (?) Or is it more correct to see it as a function. So when you say $X_i$ you actually say, whatever that function takes for the $i$th element of the population, where you have potentially chosen $i$. Sorry but i have a computing bg so it's easier for me to understand in terms of code. So it's almost if you were generate random integers (uniformly distributed) from 1 to 100 for instance, assuming you have 100 cards...

Comment: Given that we assume that each observation is a realization of a distinct random variable, the number of observations coincides with the number of the underlying random variables. So $n$ is the "sample size" ($n$ observations) which is equal to the number of random variables of which this sample constitutes a realization.

Comment: Formally speaking, a random variable is a real-valued function, indeed.

Comment: ... then for each number do something like that X[i] where X[i] actually returns you the number written on the card. So if I compare this with the def. from wiki for "sample", then my i's here are my identically distributed (iid) random variables with distribution F here F is a uniform distribution? and what you call $x_i$ (the observation) are the result of X[i]?

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to add a new answer to explain for detailed.
The problem is that: Each experiment is to draw $n$ cards independently and the result is sample average $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. We want to compute the expectation of sample average $E[Y]$. By definition,
$$E[Y]=E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]=E[X_i]$$
As for why don't we use 
$$E[Y]=\sum_i p_iX_i=\sum_i x_iP(X_i=x_i)$$
is now easy to see, since the correct formula shall be
$$E[Y]=\sum_i p_iY_i=\sum_i y_iP(Y_i=y_i)$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But as much as can now understand the first part (the top equations, first line), I don't understand the next 2. The expected value of the sample mean is equal to the sum of the sample means multiplied by the probability, then you say this is the same as the sume of the $y_i$ multiplied by the probability that $Y_i = y_i$. I do not understand how to interpret this.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I am not making an effort... I understand here the lower case letters ($x_i$ for example are the observations of the random var $X$). So what I understand is that it's a sum of observations multiplied by the probability that the random variable itself is equal to the observation). That's the part i don't understand well.

Comment: Your later response has a correct understanding. Each $y_i$ is a sample mean and $P(Y_i=y_i)$ is its corresponding probability. But the question is you don't know $P(Y_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually the expectation computed in two ways produce the same result since
   $$\sum_{i=1}p_iX_i=\sum_{i=1}\frac{n_i}{n}X_i=\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1}X_1+\sum_{i_2=1}^{n_1}X_2+...+\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_k}X_k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}X_i$$
2. I think you may mistake $X_i$ as a sample with fixed value. But you'd better regard it as only a sample with undeterministic value, a random variable. So each $X_i$ has a mean and it can be computed by using $\sum_{i=1}p_iO_i$ where $O_i$ is possible values.

Comment: Thank you Shuchang. 1) I don't understand how you go from $\sum_{i=1}p_iX_i$ to $\sum_{i=1}\frac{n_i}{n}X_i$? Do you actually mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n_i}\frac 1 {n}X_i$ in the second equation? 2) yes after thinking very hard yesterday  (I really wanted to understand what was the concept I didn't get right), I realised I was seeing X as a fixed value while in fact it means "all the possible values from the sample space". Thank you. It would be great if you could just explain (1) a bit more.

Comment: To use capital letters for (nonrandom) numbers when the OP's main trouble is to separate numbers from random variables is at best perverse.

Comment: @MarcOurens To answer 1, how do you understand the meaning of $p_i$ in your 1st question and how do you see the relation between $p_i$ and $w_i$?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang, $p_i$ is the probability that $X_i$ occurs where $X_i$ is one of the many possible outcomes from the sample space $S = {X_1, X_2, ... X_{something}}$. $p_i$ and $w_i$ for me are the same thing. $p_i$ is probability and $w_i$ is a weight but in essence $p_i = w_i$. Does it help you answering me? thank you. I just want to understand really!

Comment: @MarcOurens Yes, $p_i$ are frequencies of sampling. Can you now go through my first identity and understand it?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I understand this $\sum_{i=1}p_iX_i$ yes, it's the equation for computing the Expected value which is the sum of the outcome multiplied by their probability. I got that I think, but I don't understand what your second equation is $\sum_{i=1}{n_i \over n}X_i$. $X_i$ is the outcome from the sample space, as before, but I don't know what $n_i$ stands for! $n$ I guess is the number of possible outcomes (the size of the sample space)? What happens if this is infinite (in the case of a continuous random variable)? thank you for your patience.

Comment: @MarcOurens Since now you say $p_i=w_i$ is the frequency, then $n_i$ is of course the number of occurring of the i-th result in total $n$ times experiments. So $n$ would not be infinite. I think you shall clarify these pairs of notions. Frequency vs Probability and Outcome vs Random variable.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang. I am sorry, I simply don't understand. We agree that $p_i$ and $w_i$ are actually the same thing. if you look at the example that I gave above with the 10 cards labelled 0,1,2 I showed I know how to compute the expected value using probability distribution (using the $p_i$s). The outcomes in this experience are 0,1,2. I think I understand the difference between outcome now (they define the sample space) and random variable (it can take on any value from that sample space). I am not sure though that I would make a distinction between frequency and probability (to continue).

Comment: (continue) to me they are the same. A probability is the frequency at which an outcome can occur. In the card example, Pr(0) or frequency that a card with number 0 will show up is 0.2. Now if we don't use the equation to compute the expected value when you don't know the probability distribution, but draw samples instead, for me $X_1$ represents the first card you draw from the cards, and $X_2$ is the second card, etc. I also understand that some people draw 3 cards for example and compute the sample mean and this is what they call $X_1$ (the average of the 3 cards). (continue)

Comment: (continue), so I think I would need someone (you would be nice) to explain me what you mean by experiment, and what $n_i$ is and the difference between $n_i$ and $n$. For me an experiment, is when you draw 1 or more cards (say 3 and the number of drawn cards is $n$) and use the result of these 1 (n=1) or 3 (n=3) draws to compute a random number $X_1$. This r.v. can be computed by either summing up the numbers on the card (sample sum) or summing up the numbers and dividing by the numb. of cards drawn (n, sample mean). And this process for me is what you call an experiment (and result is $X_1$).

Comment: Sorry but I've to make sure, whether you mean why don't compute $E[\bar X]$ as $E[\sum_i p_i X_i]$ or simply $\sum_i p_i X_i$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang, doing my research on my side, I think things are a bit better in my mind now, I do understand better what X is (talking as well with Alecos above). So I should see it more as a function X(w) mapping the outcome of an experiment (heads/tails for instance) to a number (0,1) and X is a function defined on the probability space. Thus of course by definition the expected value of X is the mean. So I understand (2) well now but still have problem to understand why we can't compute the expected value of the sample mean as a sum of weighted sample mean ?

Comment: @MarcOurens Because you don't know the weight of sample mean

Comment: @ShuchangZhang. I see so you say because you don't know their weight then you can't use this equation to make that proof? isn't there anyway at all to make that proof using the expected value equation? It seems like unsatisfying to me (as is "I can't prove it using the original equation, so I will prove it another way")? isn't there something that says that as the sample size appraches infinity then the weight becomes 1, etc.?

Comment: Of course you can use but considering not known weight, you have to transform it to other forms that you can directly computed. Now assume your formula's feasible, you can try whether you can get the answer.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang "Of course you can use but considering not known weight, you have to transform it to other forms that you can directly computed" if this is feasible could you please show me how? I am definitely not good enough to do this myself...

Comment: @MarcOurens I have already shown that in my initial answer.